# What is the value of: $\cot^{-1}(\cot(\frac{3\pi}4))$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

What is the value of: $\cot^{-1}(\cot(\frac{3\pi}4))$?

The output given by the WolframAlpha is $\frac{-\pi}4$ and by the Symbolab is $\frac{3\pi}4$.

Which one is correct ?

Comment: It looks like Symbolab is taking the range of the inverse cotangent function to be $(0, \pi)$, while WolframAlpha is taking it to be $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, 0) \cup (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.  The issue is that there no universal convention for the range of the inverse cotangent function.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, it depends on the branch on which you define the arc-cotangent. Indeed as cotangent is a periodic function you can't have an inverse on its entire domain. But if you restrict it to a fundamental domain (open interval of length $\pi$) then you can define an inverse on that subdomain.

Typically the arc-cotangent on the fundamental domain $(-\pi,0)$ o $(0,\pi)$. In the first case you get the answer of WA, in the second of SY.

Comment: cot^(-1)(cot(x)) =x in the domain (0, π). It can be visualized in Desmos. Since 3pi/4 is in this domain, should not the answer be 3pi/4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The cotangent of $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is $-1$, but the arc-cotangent of $-1$ could be either.

Comment: If both are correct, why both engines are showing only one output. If there are multiple outputs both engines show those too. 
I even tweeted this to both, only Symbolab replied that the answer was 3pi/4.

Comment: That is a good point Mr. Kumar, and I am not sure, but I do know that the arc-cotangent of $-1$ has two viable answers.